# YOLO V4 Tiny - Making more photos from one annotated image

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection, yolo

I am trying to make a yolo v4 tiny custom data set using google collab. I am using labelImg.py for image annotations which is shown in https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg.

I have annotated one image as shown as below,

[image: Annotated Image]

The .txt file with the annotated coordinates looks as following,

```
0 0.580859 0.502083 0.303906 0.404167
```

I only have one class which is calculator class. I want to use this one image to produce 4 more annotated images. I want to rotate the annotated image 45 degrees every time and create a new annotated image and a.txt coordinate file. I have seen something like this done in roboflow but I cant figure out how to do it manually with a python script. Is it possible to do it? If so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look into the repo and article below for python based data augmentation including rotation, shearing, resizing, translation, flipping etc.

https://github.com/Paperspace/DataAugmentationForObjectDetection

https://blog.paperspace.com/data-augmentation-for-bounding-boxes/

If you are using [AlexeyAB's darknet repo](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet) for yolov4, then there are some augmentations you can use to increase training data size and variation.

https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/wiki/CFG-Parameters-in-the-%5Bnet%5D-section

Look into `Data augmentation` section where you can use various defined augmentations for object detection by adding them to yolo `cfg` file.